# Pyspark DF groupBy giving error - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Pyspark dataframe whose schema definition is

[image]

Last 4 columns - *genres_value,production_companies_values,production_countries_values* and *spoken_languages_values* are derived column after parsing Json strings and then added to original dataframe.

I am trying to run groupBy as `df2.groupBy("production_countries_values").count().show()` but its throwing error - 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

I tried 'select','filter' on the column but these commands return without any error whereas groupBy on all four new columns that was added after parsing is throwing same error - 'NoneType' object is not iterable. Groupby works on other columns of DF.

Command - `df2.where(col('production_countries_values')=='unknown').show()` also throw error 'NoneType' object is not iterable

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like production_countries_values column has Null Values so you cant group Null columns together. You can use when condition and replace Null values with some default value and then group-by will work.

Comment: It does not have null values. When I tried command - df2.where(col('production_countries_values')=='unknown').show(), it also gave same error - 'NoneType' object is not iterable.  Some function works on the column like 'select' and some don't work.